# AttributeError:'NavigableString' object as no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, xml

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url=urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.theguardian.com/international/rss")

xml=BeautifulSoup(url,features='xml')

for item in xml.findAll('link')[3]:  
    news=urllib.request.urlopen(item.text).read()
    print(news)
```

When i ran this code it is throwing error: `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'`. How can i solve this problemI am new to coding,any help will be highly welcome.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this way I believe it will work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.theguardian.com/international/rss")

xml = BeautifulSoup(url, features='xml')

for item in xml.findAll('link')[3]:
    news = urllib.request.urlopen(item).read()
    print(news)
```